# How to append a string in android?

Tags: android

i'm using a variable:-

String[] string;

how to append it?

Comment: Assumedly he wants to append a String to the end of the array?

Comment: yes thats what i was thinking.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string array is not dynamic. It has the size you set it should have when you initialize it. To have a dynamic list of strings use `ArrayList<String>` instead.

To append to a normal string, take a look at `StringBuilder`